# Web.config URL Rewrites - HTTPS and Non-WWW

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis, url-rewriting

I need to have both `https` and `non-www` rewrites, while also **NOT HARDCODING the domain**, since we have numerous servers. This needs to be in the `web.config`, not in `IIS`.

I've read numerous articles:

- http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference
- http://madskristensen.net/post/url-rewrite-and-the-www-subdomain
- [how to set asp.net web.config rewrite http to https and www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597716/how-to-set-asp-net-web-config-rewrite-http-to-https-and-www-to-non-www)

The `https` rewrite works, the `non-www` does not.

```
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Remove WWW" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <!--<add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="*://www.*" />-->
        <!--<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*://www.*" />-->
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*www.*" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      // i've also tried
      // url="{C:2}/{R:1}"
      // url="{C:1}/{C:2}"
    </rule>
```

I tested the regex for `^.*www.*` on a regex tester and it was matching `www.testing.com` but not `testing.com` - so I would assume the pattern would catch it.

I need the URLs to redirect from:

- testing.com  --->  https://testing.com
- www.testing.com  ---> https://testing.com
- www.testing.com/xyz/  ---> https://testing.com/xyz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was my own issue - there was no DNS for the `www`, therefore the redirect wouldn't resolve on it's own.

Code used:

```
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Remove WWW" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="*://www.*" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a "Canonical domain name" rule.
[image: IIS 10]

The soulution Rob found works fine as well. Mine seems to be a bit easier IMHO.